# Extract equally spaced subarrays from an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array:

```
v = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20];
```

I want to extract multiple arrays of length 3 equally spaced by 6 elements, starting at the fifth element of `v`, and then combine them together:

```
v1 = [5 6 7];
v2 = [11 12 13];
v3 = [17 18 19];

v_combined = [5 6 7 11 12 13 17 18 19];
```

Are there any simple ways to do this without using a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for `m` elements spaces by `n` elements starting from `k` you can use

```
k=5;
m=3;
n=6;

I=1:numel(v);
v_combined = v((I>=k) & mod(I-k,n)<m)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using logical indexing. You need to create an index mask like this

```
idx = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
```

which you can create like this:

```
idx = false(size(v))
k = 5
idx(k:end) = ~mod(floor((0:numel(v)-k)/3),2)
```

And finally

```
v_combined = v(idx)
```